# Do I have to get a ssl certificate to send to my own browser responses to https requests?

Tags: python, sockets, ssl

I have to make a basic proxy which intercepts the requests of the browser and sends back a standard response. It doesn't work if I try to send the response in response to a https request. The code I'm using is:

```
#after the server socket starts listening
conn, addr = server.accept()
request = conn.recv(4096)
print request
conn.send(b"HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n\n<p>Hello</p>")
conn.close()
```

Now for https requests, e.g.:

```
Got request:
CONNECT www.google.com:443 HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:28.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/28.0
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive
Connection: keep-alive
Host: www.google.com
```

I've tried sending the same response, but the browser shows "The connection was interrupted". The response has certainly been sent though. Am I right in thinking that to overcome this, I need to get a ssl certificate and send the response through a ssl socket?
(I'm not asking this because I'm too lazy to try it out, but setting up the certificate should take some time so I'd like to verify with someone who knows before wasting hours on a wrong hypothesis)

Comment: You can create your own cert with openssl.

Comment: So _that_ is the cause of the refused connection, right?